How is it decided which impl to use for fully qualified trait method?
Given the below example, how does Rust know how to call the correct method implementation? I believe this can't be determined at runtime so Rust must use the statically known type of the self argument provided the Foo::get_foo() calls to convert the calls to something semantically equivalent to Foo_for_Bar::get_foo(&bar) and Foo_for_Baz::get_foo(&baz)?
trait Foo {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Bar {}
impl Foo for Bar {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> i32 {
        5
    }
}

struct Baz {}
impl Foo for Baz {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> i32 {
        6
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar {};
    assert_eq!(Foo::get_foo(&bar), 5);
    let baz = Baz {};
    assert_eq!(Foo::get_foo(&baz), 6);
}


fyi: Foo::get_foo(&bar) isn't fully qualified, <Bar as Foo>::get_foo(&bar) is.

Just like it knows when you call bar.get_foo().
